# Is there a way to move all files with specific file extensions from one folder to another in S3 using Boto3 python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to move all files of specific file extensions from one folder to another using the S3 API.

The code I'm using to move files is:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource(‘s3’)

s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “newpath/to/object_B.txt”).copy_from(
 CopySource=”path/to/your/object_A.txt”)

s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “path/to/your/object_A.txt”).delete()
```

Is there a way to modify this to move just the files that have specific extensions (e.g. `.txt` and `.csv`) ?

Comment: It can only copy one object at a time. Therefore: get a list of objects in the source path, use a `for` loop on the list and the use `if name.endswith(...)` to determine whether to trigger a Copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('bucket-name')

for object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='source_path/'):
  if object.key.endswith('.txt') or object.key.endswith('.csv'):
    bucket.Object(...).copy(...)
    object.delete(...)
```

You will need to modify the target key to include the destination path.

Answer (score 0):

Used some code from @John

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    src_bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket-test-all-files')
    dest_bucket_jpg = s3.Bucket('mybucket-test-jpg-files')
    dest_bucket_png = s3.Bucket('mybucket-test-png-files')
    
    for object in src_bucket.objects.all():
        if object.key.endswith('.jpg') or object.key.endswith('.jpeg'):
            copy_source = {
                'Bucket': src_bucket,
                'Key': object.key
            }
            dest_bucket_jpg.copy(copy_source, object.key)
            object.delete()
        elif object.key.endswith('.png'):
            copy_source = {
                'Bucket': src_bucket,
                'Key': object.key
            }
            dest_bucket_png.copy(copy_source, object.key)
            object.delete()
        else: 
            print("Not copying any objects with diff file-types")
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Files Copied Successfully')
    }
```